# if statement in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming

I have two variables **a >= 1** and **b = {0, 1}**, so *a* is an integer positive variable */=0*, and *b* is a binary variable. I want to make *b=1* when *a=1*, and *b=0* when *a>1*, and I need to write it into a linear program. So the condition is:

```
if a=1 then b=1 else b=0
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if a<2 then b=1 else b=0
```

because *a* cannot be 0 due to other constraints.

anyone knows how to write it in a linear program?

Comment: This is not related to "linear programming". What is programming language? What are _exact_ constraints for solving this task? What's your progress so far?

Comment: I think the OP just misuses the term "Linear Programming"

Comment: I'm writing a linear program, not a high level programming language program. I think the correct answer to my question is:

a <= b+My;
a >= b+2y;
b+y = 1;

where y is a binary variable and M is a big number.
can somebody confirm that?

Answer (score 3):

OP, *provided that M is greater than any possible value of the positive integer a*, **the answer you suggest in your comment is correct**, namely:

> a <= b+My; a >= b+2y; b+y = 1, where y is binary

To confirm, we just have to examine this set of statements to demonstrate that (1) the desired outcomes are feasible and (2) all other outcomes are infeasible.  Since b is a binary variable in this case, "all other outcomes" means simply the other outcome:  b=0 vs b=1.

---

### Proof

#### (a = 1) => (b = 1)

To begin, consider the condition:

> if a=1 then b=1

**Let a=1** in your suggested answer, obtaining:

```
1 <= b+My; 1 >= b+2y; b+y = 1
```

Clearly, **b=1 is feasible**, because we can find a value of y that allows all of the statements to be true (namely, y=0):

```
1 <= 1+M*0; 1 >= 1+2*0; 1+0 = 1
```

On the other hand, if we **let b=0**:

```
1 <= 0+My; 1 >= 0+2y; 0+y = 1
```

This implies that **y=1**, which **leads to a contradiction** in the second statement:

```
1 <= 0+M*1; 1 >= 0+2*1; 0+1 = 1
```

*Therefore, **if a=1, then it must be that b=1**.*

---

#### (a > 1) => (b = 0)

Next, consider the [contrapositive](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp2/lcontrap.htm) of the prior condition (to satisfy the "else" clause):

> if a>1 then b=0

Following the same procedure, **let a>1** in your suggested answer - *I'll put a 5, but keep in mind that this could be any integer greater than 1*:

```
5 <= b+My; 5 >= b+2y; b+y = 1
```

We see that **b=0 is feasible**, because we can find a value of y that makes all of the statements true (namely, y=1):

```
5 <= 0+M*1; 5 >= 0+2*1; 0+1 = 1
```

*(This is the point at which it is important that M be greater than any possible value of a, otherwise the first statement could be untrue.)*

On the other hand, if we **let b=1**:

```
5 <= 1+My; 5 >= 1+2y; 1+y = 1
```

This implies that **y=0**, which **leads to a contradiction** in the first inequality:

```
5 <= 1+M*0; 5 >= 1+2*0; 1+0 = 1
```

*Therefore, **if a>1, then it must be that b=0**.*

---

### Conclusion

Therefore, this set of statements

```
a <= b+My; a >= b+2y; b+y = 1, where y is binary
```

**satisfies the condition**:

> if a=1 then b=1 else b=0

Answer (score -1):

An example in C++:

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // declare variables at top...
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;

    // then some code that changes the initial value of a...

    // code to check the value of a and change the value of b...
    if (a == 1) {
        b = 1;
    } else if (a > 1) {
        b = 0;
    }

    // output value of b
    std::cout << "Value of b: " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm writing a linear program, not a high level programming language program. I think the correct answer to my question is: 

a <= b+My;
a >= b+2y;
b+y = 1;

where y is a binary variable and M is a big number. can somebody confirm that?